# How do I sum double and int using Expression.Add?

Tags: c#, .net, types, expression

I want to use `Expression.Add` to sum two data types, which might be a  `double` and an `int` (or any other mismatched pair), like this:

```
var pLeft = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "left");
var pRight = Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), "right");

var addition = Expression.Add(pLeft, pRight);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, double, double>>(addition, pLeft, pRight).Compile();

var res = method(1, 0.5);
```

However, I am promptly informed that:

```
The binary operator Add is not defined for the types 'System.Int32' and 'System.Double'.
```

It's clear that the `+` operator isn't defined for every possible pair of numbers, but that some sort of implicit conversion goes on when I write something like `var x = 1 + 0.5`. Is there a way to emulate this conversion using an expression, or otherwise a way to sum such types using an expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Expression.Convert` to convert one of the parameters to the type of the opposite one.

Expression trees do not have an "**opinion**" on how implicit  conversions should work because they are not language specific. C# has different rules for implicit conversions than VB.NET for example. Expression trees take a neutral stance and require explicit conversions.

For example, a performance oriented language might decide to implicitly convert the double to int because it prefers performance by default. C# prefers precision in this case. Expression trees can't decide this problem generally.

Comment: How do I know which parameter to convert to which? Is there a way to check if a conversion exists? Will `Expression.Convert` work for user-defined conversions?

Comment: This logic is entirely up to you. It is not built-in because it is programming language specific. This is the point of my answer.